# C++. Непреднамеренное модифицирование временного объекта

Tags: c++

В коде возвращается объект по значению, но не const. Задумался, можно ли этот временный объект модифицировать подобно non-const ссылке передаваемой из метода/функции. Проверил - модифицируется.

**Вопрос:** необходимо ли при передаче объекта по значению, передавать его в виде константы? Что на счёт структур и вообще всех lvalue? Является ли переданный по значению объект lvalue, раз он временный?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Если объект не константен, то его можно модифицировать. Временный он или не временный - роли не играет. Временность и модифицируемость - совершенно ортогональные характеристики.

  При этом константность тоже в общем случае не означает физической немодифицируемости, ибо `mutable` поля могут быть модифицированы даже в константных объектах.
- *Объект* не может быть lvalue или не-lvalue. Категория значения - это свойство *выражений*, а не объектов. Что вы сможете делать с объектом зависит от того, через какое выражение вы к этому объекту обращаетесь. К одному и тому же объекту можно доступаться через разные выражения и видеть его и как lvalue, и как rvalue одновременно.
- > Задумался, можно ли этот временный объект модифицировать подобно non-const ссылке передаваемой из метода/функции. Проверил - модифицируется.

  Модифицироваться-то он модифицируется, но на этом подобие с "ссылкой передаваемой из метода/функции" заканчивается. В случае возврата по значению ваши модификации, разумеется, модифицируют копию и не затрагивают оригинальный объект.
- > Является ли переданный по значению объект lvalue, раз он временный?

  Не совсем ясно, о чем здесь вообще идет речь. Переданные по значению параметры функций не являются временным объектами. Они являются [почти] обычными автоматическим объектами. У них есть *имена*. О какой "временности" может идти речь?

  А результат функции, возвращенный по значению, по определению не является lvalue.
- > необходимо ли при передаче объекта по значению, передавать его в виде константы?

  Имеет ли смысл передаваемому (или возвращаемому) по значению объекту давать константный тип - отчасти вопрос личных предпочтений. Никакой "необходимости" в этом обычно нет.

Comment: Вообще, переданные по значению объекты (в широком смысле, в том числе экземпляры класса) являются временными. Их существование в большинстве случаев закончится раньше, чем закончится блок, в который они пришли из функции. И нет, они неименованные, ведь указывается только тип возвращаемого объекта.

Comment: @Παν μέτρον άριστον: Я не понимаю, о чем вы говорите. Во-первых, вы как будто используете слово "переданные", но на самом деле веде речь о *возвращенных* из функции объектах. Это странно и сбивает с толку. Во-вторых, в современном С++ уже нет никаких "временных объектов" при возвращении значения из функции. Операнд `return` *напрямую* инициализирует объект-получатель в вызывающем коде (и это еще если не произошло RVO). Никаких промежуточных временных объектов гарантированно не создается.

Comment: Да, я имел ввиду именно передачу значения из функции, а не в функцию. На счёт RVO, разные есть оптимизации у компилятора, всех нюансов не знаю, но тем не менее, знаю, что временных объектов (хотя бы потенциальных) стоит по возможности избегать.

Comment: @Παν μέτρον άριστον: Спецификация языка уже *гарантирует* отсутствие промежуточных временных объектов при возвращении значения из функции. Разумеется, если вы сами не захотите его материализовать. То есть лишних временных объектов объектов не будет.